# Unity3d error CS1061: Type x does not contain a definition for y. But it does?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I'm running into the quite simple aforementioned error. I thought I'd fix it quite quickly, but even after quite some searching, I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. I Have the following Interface:

```
public interface ITemperatureEmitter
{
    float CurrentTemperatureAddon { get; }
}
```

I implement this in two other (empty for now) Interfaces:

```
public interface ITemperatureEmitterEnvironment : ITemperatureEmitter

public interface ITemperatureEmitterSphere : ITemperatureEmitter
```

Subsequently I use these three interfaces in the following class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TemperatureReceiver : MonoBehaviour, ITemperatureReceiver
{
    public float PerceivedTemperature;

    // Serialized for debug purposes
    [SerializeField] private List<ITemperatureEmitterSphere> temperatureEmitterSpheres;
    [SerializeField] private List<ITemperatureEmitterEnvironment> temperatureEmitterEnvironments;
    [SerializeField] private float environmentTemperature;
    [SerializeField] private float temperatureToModifyBy;
    [SerializeField] private float currentTemperatureAddon;
    [SerializeField] private float appliedTemperatureAddon;
    [SerializeField] private float totalTemperatureAddon;

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdatePerceivedTemperature();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterSphere>() != null)
        {
            temperatureEmitterSpheres.Add(other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterSphere>());
        }
        else if (other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterEnvironment>() != null)
        {
            temperatureEmitterEnvironments.Add(other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterEnvironment>());
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterSphere>() != null)
        {
            temperatureEmitterSpheres.Remove(other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterSphere>());
        }
        else if (other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterEnvironment>() != null)
        {
            temperatureEmitterEnvironments.Remove(other.GetComponent<ITemperatureEmitterEnvironment>());
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePerceivedTemperature()
    {
        ModifyPerceivedTemperature(temperatureEmitterSpheres);
        ModifyPerceivedTemperature(temperatureEmitterEnvironments);
    }

    private void ModifyPerceivedTemperature<ITemperatureEmitter>(List<ITemperatureEmitter> list)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                currentTemperatureAddon += item.CurrentTemperatureAddon;
            }
            currentTemperatureAddon = currentTemperatureAddon / list.Count;
            appliedTemperatureAddon = PerceivedTemperature;
            temperatureToModifyBy = currentTemperatureAddon = appliedTemperatureAddon;
            PerceivedTemperature += temperatureToModifyBy;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `item.CurrentTemperatureAddon` in the `ModifyPercievedTemperature` method emits "*error CS1061: Type `ITemperatureEmitter` does not contain a definition for `CurrentTemperatureAddon` and no extension method `CurrentTemperatureAddon` of type `ITemperatureEmitter` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?*"

`ITemperatureEmitter` quite literally does contain a definition for `CurrentTemperatureAddonm`... Anyone has an idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misdeclared `ModifyPerceivedTemperature`

```
private void ModifyPerceivedTemperature<ITemperatureEmitter>(List<ITemperatureEmitter> list)
```

Here you use `ITemperatureEmitter` as the name of the **generic parameter**. So in this scope, it no longer means the `interface ITemperatureEmitter`, but the generic argument.

Just remove the generic parameter, it's not used anyway:

```
private void ModifyPerceivedTemperature(List<ITemperatureEmitter> list)
```

Now you simply have a `List<ITemperatureEmitter> list` as argument and all your `var item in list` are really of type `ITemperatureEmitter`, and not of a generic type.

Comment: I see! My lack of knowledge about generic parameters comes into play here I'm afraid. I wanted to be able to stuff both `ITemperatureEmitterEnvironment` and `ITemperatureEmitterSphere` in the `ModifyPerceivedTempereture` method, so I fooled around until I could... Guess I should just make two methods :) Thanks a lot for the clear answer!